# I have to get data from the following url which contains the data in json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

http://te.chni.ca/twitter.api/tweet.php

I tried all tutorials but unable to get the data from that please help me 
try to get atleast one attribute so i can try the remaining ones

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Twitter</title>

</head>
<body>

<button id="initquery">Search</button>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#initquery').click(function(){

        $.getJSON('http://te.chni.ca/twitter.api/tweet.php',function(data){
            var item=[];
            $.each(data,function(key,val){
                items.push('<li id="'+key+'">'+val+'</li>');

                });

                $('<ul/>',{
                    'class':'interests-list',
                    html:items.join('')
                    }).appendTo('body');

            });


        });

    });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show some code that you have tried. What is your actual problem?

Comment: hi @MoritzPetersen i edited my question thank you in advance i tried the code and error says that XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://te.chni.ca/twitter.api/tweet.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. so i need to get atleast one attribute into the html page so that i can do the remaining

Comment: You need to be using jsonp

Comment: It would also be better to move <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> into the <head> of your page or down at the bottom of the <body> instead of right in the middle of your html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using jsonp.  Do you see the parenthesis around the response from that API?  That is tell-tale sign that this is intended to be jsonp.

You should use `ajax()` method for this:

```
$ajax(
   url: 'http://te.chni.ca/twitter.api/tweet.php',
   dataType: 'jsonp',
   success: function(data) {
       // your success function
   }
);
```

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access iam getting this error @mike brant